What is "Fred" Weasley's full name?
The name Fred is usually short for  Frederick or Alfred, or non-English variations such as Alfredo.
Is there any canon as to which was  Fred Weasley's  first name?
Or was "Fred" his actual name?
Canon would be something written by Rowling. Wikis or comments by fans aren't canon. And the fact that he's only ever called Fred isn't proof.

HarryPotter.com lists his name as Fred Weasley, no middle name.

Fred and George Weasley
The cheekiest Weasley boys were two characters with doubly interesting
names – though neither have middle names. George is derived from the
Greek ‘farmer, earth worker’. While he was most definitely not a
farmer, he was a born inventor and he and his brother worked very hard
to build Weasleys’ Wizard Wheezes from the ground up.
Similarly, Fred’s name means ‘peaceful ruler’, which, as he was the
more outgoing of the Weasley twins, definitely has to be ironic.
Fred’s endless tricks, pranks and rejection of authority were
testament to the fact that he was anything but ‘peaceful’.
The revealing etymology of the Weasley family tree


And yes, you can yell at me all you like about this not being written by JK Rowling, but suffice to say that this site isn't in the business of inventing high level canon or renaming characters without being very very careful

I think this is still a case of  "the fact that he's only ever called Fred isn't proof."

@Pete - They definitively state the full name of every other character. Why do you assume that he has an extra hidden name? Hundreds of kids are called Fred every year without having to be a Fredrick or an Alfred or a Manfred.

If it means "peaceful ruler" then it must be Frederick. If it really is only "Fred" then that just means "peace". Alfred (and Alfredo) instead means "elf counsel".

i.e. that Ancestry page is largely wrong (it's also of German origin, not English)
